# Trigger: Something wrong with the code

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle11g

I have the following information with me:

```
The EMP table is as follows:

EMPNO , ENAME, JOB, MGR, HIREDATE, SAL,COMM,DEPTNO


Here is the DEPT table:

DEPTNO, DNAME, LOC
```

Based on the following question:

**create a table to log employee terminations. Include the empno, emp name, the date hired, the date terminated, and the name of the oracle user who 
 terminated the employee.**

I have created the following table in Oracle 11g, SQL Plus as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE employee_terminations_log(
       empno   number(4),
       emp_name char(8),
       datehired date,
       dateterminated date,
       dbuser char(8) );
```

Now, based on the following question :

**Create a trigger on the emp table to insert relevant information into the employee termination log. The trigger must execute every time an employee is deleted.**

I wrote the code for the trigger as follows:

```
create or replace trigger emp_termination_trigger
after delete of empno on emp
for each row
begin
      insert into employee_termination-log
      values(:old.empno,:old.emp_name,:old.hiredate,sysdate,user);
end;
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
8  /
after delete of empno on emp
             *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-04073: column list not valid for this trigger type
```

Could anyone please tell me what's wrong in the above code for trigger? Basically I have
to deleter the whole employee row and for that I have used the
following statement in the above code.

after delete of empno on emp

Please let me know what's wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like another typo, should be employee_terminations_log:

```
create or replace trigger emp_termination_trigger
after delete on emp
for each row
begin
      insert into employee_terminations_log
      values(:old.empno,:old.emp_name,:old.hiredate,sysdate,user);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
create or replace trigger emp_termination_trigger
after delete on emp
for each row
begin
      insert into employee_termination_log
      values(:old.empno,:old.emp_name,:old.hiredate,sysdate,user);
end;
```

You also had a spelling mistake with the `insert into` line

Comment: I replied separately. Please check. Thanks !